# Why are my thumbnails being Squished? Isotope

Tags: jquery, performance, thumbnails, jquery-isotope, image-gallery

I am using Isotope for my thumbnail gallery. Everything worked great while I was building it. But after I published it to to my ftp the thumbnails started squishing vertically. Different thumbnails squish everytime I refresh. Anyone know why its doing this?

http://thecarlossanchez.com/Galleries/stills.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is your loading jQuery 2x and 2 different versions. Pick the newest version and load only one. Secondly, you are loading imagesloaded.js but not calling it for isotope. The thumbs are squished because unloaded images can throw off Isotope layouts and cause item elements to overlap, which is why you need imagesloaded.

Try this:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
$grid.isotope({
itemSelector: '.element-item',
layoutMode: 'masonry'
});
});
```